# How to make custom TLS session in Scapy and make GET request?

Tags: ssl, https, scapy

I use scapy to make custom TCP session in userspace and send GET request to server to recieve json string. I can do it with simple HTTP, but i have no idea how to make it with TLS.

There is TLS layer in scapy, but there are no documentation how to make TLS session (even TLS handshake) and i cant find any information about it in whole internet :(

Only i can do is to use TLS Automaton, but it make TCP connection automatically, but i want to build it manually and use for TLS connection.

does anyone can help me? my brain is on fire :(

Comment: why not use the proper Python libraries to do TCP/HTTP/TLS connections? For the later you have `ssl` module included in Python, or external `pyopenssl`.

Comment: i should control TCP flags, MSS, windows size, ect. With scapy i can do it.